# How to ensure that the serialization and deserialization with WebServices is symmetric?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, json, serialization

I have a couple of standard ASP.NET web methods that I'm calling from javascript with a parameter that is of a custom class in form

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(MyOtherSubclass))]
public class MyClass
{
     [DataMember]
     public MyOtherClass MyMember { get; set; }
}
```

where `MyOtherClass` is a class marked with `Serializable` but not with `DataContract` attribute (I don't have a control over its generation). There is a couple of subclasses of `MyOtherClass`, e.g. `MyOtherSubclass` :

```
[Serializable]
public class MyOtherSubClass : MyOtherClass
{
    private string valueField;
    public string Value 
    {
        get { return valueField; }
        set { valueField = value; }
    }
}
```

When I use the DataContractJsonSerializer to serialize an object of MyClass directly, I get a result similar to

```
{ "MyMember" : { "__type" : "MyOtherSubClass:#Namespace", "valueField" : "xxx" } }
```

However, when I pass such a JSON into the web method request from javascript, I get an exception while deserializing. I have experimented a little bit and found that when using the following one instead

```
{ "MyMember" : { "___type" : "Namespace.MyOtherSubClass", "Value" : "xxx" } }
```

the deserialization works without any problems.

Is there any way to configure the DataContractJsonSerializer in such a way that it would produce the JSON in the second form, so that the web method arguments deserialization would work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET WebMethods use [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx), so try serializing with it. You might need a custom type resolver in order to include this property:

```
public class Parent
{
    public string ParentProp { get; set; }
}

public class Child: Parent
{
    public string ChildProp { get; set; }
}

public class CustomResolver : JavaScriptTypeResolver
{
    public override Type ResolveType(string id)
    {
        return Type.GetType(id);
    }

    public override string ResolveTypeId(Type type)
    {
        return type.ToString();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var o = new Child
        {
            ParentProp = "parent prop",
            ChildProp = "child prop",
        };

        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(new CustomResolver());
        var s = serializer.Serialize(o);
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```